# How to disable and enable javascript buttons according to a specific condition?

Tags: javascript, ajax, mongodb, function, express-handlebars

[image: This is my cart page.]

I want to disable the (-) button when this page is loaded and the value between these buttons are equal to 1.

### 1)hbs code

```
<tbody>

    {{#each products}}

     <tr>

     <h1 id="Quantity" hidden>{{this.quantity}}</h1>

     <td><img src="/product-images/{{this.product._id}}.jpg" style="width:70px;height:70px" alt=""> 
  </td>

     <td>{{this.product.Name}}</td>

     <td>Rs.{{this.product.Price}}</td>

     <td>

     <button class="btn btn-info mr-3 cart-item-count" id="button(-)" 
   onclick="changeQuantity('{{this._id}}','{{this.product._id}}','{{../user._id}}',-1)">-</button>
 
     <span id="{{this.product._id}}">{{this.quantity}}</span>

     <button class="btn btn-info mr-3 cart-item-count" id="button(-)" 
    onclick="changeQuantity('{{this._id}}','{{this.product._id}}','{{../user._id}}',1)">+</button>

     <td>

     <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Remove</button>

     </td>

     </tr>

     {{/each}}

     </tbody>
```

### 2)Array of products

[image: Array of products]

### 3)Code used for button disabling and enabling.

```
 let Quantity = document.getElementById('Quantity').innerHTML
    console.log(Quantity)
    if (Quantity == 1) {
        document.getElementById('button(-)').disabled = true
    } else {
        document.getElementById('button(-)').disabled = false
    }
    
    function changeQuantity(cartId, proId, userId, count) {
        count = parseInt(count)
        let quantity = parseInt(document.getElementById(proId).innerHTML)
        let qty = quantity + count
        console.log(qty)
        if (qty > 1 ) {
            document.getElementById('button(-)').disabled = false
        } else if (qty == 1 || qty==10) {
            document.getElementById('button(-)').disabled = true
        }

        if(qty==10){
            document.getElementById('button(+)').disabled = true
        }else{
            document.getElementById('button(+)').disabled = false
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: '/change-product-quantity',
            data: {
                cart: cartId,
                product: proId,
                user: userId,
                count: count,
                quantity: qty
            },
            method: 'post',
            success: (response) => {

                document.getElementById(proId).innerHTML = quantity + count
                document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = response.total

            }
        })
    }
```

### Note:

Above code is working fine when the cart page having only one set of product. But, in case of multiple product lists(as you can see in the image given above)it's not working as I expected. In other words, I want to control each product's buttons separately without overriding one another.

How to do that ?

Comment: An ID must be unique across the whole document. You are currently repeating all IDs on each row. `getElementById()` can't work, because it's expecting one and only one element.

Comment: how to give seperate id's ?

Comment: Givin one unique ID to each element isn't even the solution. If you have 50 elements, you'll have to attach manually 50 times an event listener. Waaaay too heavy and overkill. What you want is a class. Give the same class `<button class="btnRemove" data-target="{{this.product.id}}">`. Then you can attach one click handler to all buttons at the same time, and `onclick` read the `data-target` attribute, so you know which product to delete.

Comment: Remove  button is working fine. But the problem arise on increment and decrement buttons. If I press on one button in the first row it affecting second's row's button as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Identidying each products using unique ids would be help to solve this issue.